# How to handle onActivityResult (by third-party SDK) in jetpack compose

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I know similar question has been asked multiple times about `How to handle onActivityResult()` but this is different.

I'm using a third-party library (Paytm All-in-One SDK, to be precise) which provide result on `onActivityResult`. I know about `ActivityResultContract` but issue is, intent creation is handled by that sdk and I am not sure what to pass inside launcher of `rememberLauncherForActivityResult()`. SDK docs mention that I need to use following line to start their activity but how can i convert that line of code to use with `ActivityResultContract`?

```
transactionManager.startTransaction(activity, requestCode)
```

Comment: Here's the legacy version if you need full code [link](https://www.blueappsoftware.com/paytm-all-in-one-android-tutorial/)

Comment: Any clue or snippet you got?

Comment: @AliNawaz Nope, I just used separate activity for now.

Answer (score 1):

I came up with an idea which is working fine for me, here are steps:

1 - Identify the activity under which your composable function is triggered, in case of single activity probably it will be your MainActivity.

2 - Put a public method to create and initiate the intent and observe onActivityResult using composable type approach in your MainActivity like this:

Launcher to observe result:

```
var resultLauncher = registerForActivityResult(
    ActivityResultContracts.StartActivityForResult()
) { result -> }
```

To launch this:

```
        fun startCustomFlow () { 
        val intent = customIntenetMaker.createActivityIntent(context = this@MainActivity)

        resultLauncher.launch(intent)}
```

3 - Now you are all set for getting this response within your main activity.

4 - Its time to have a reference of your activity in your composable function which you can get as below.

```
val activity = LocalContext.current as MainActivity
```

5 - As you have got activity reference now using this reference you can trigger your custom solution flow in composable function using:

```
activity.startCustomFLow()
```

Now you are all set to play further based on your needs :)

Answer (score -1):

Handling onActivityResult in Jetpack Compose when the intent is created and started by a 3rd party SDK requires a slightly different approach. Since Jetpack Compose promotes a declarative and unidirectional data flow, you need to integrate the onActivityResult callback from the SDK into your Composable's state management.

Here's a general guideline on how you can achieve this:

Create a ViewModel: Create a ViewModel that will manage the interaction with the 3rd party SDK and hold the results.

```
import androidx.lifecycle.ViewModel

class MyViewModel : ViewModel() {
    // LiveData or State variable to hold the result from the 3rd party SDK
    // You can use StateFlow, LiveData, MutableState or any other state management mechanism.
}
```

Integrate the SDK: Integrate the 3rd party SDK in your ViewModel. This may involve creating an intent and starting an activity from the SDK.

```
class MyViewModel : ViewModel() {
// ...

fun startThirdPartyActivity() {
    /* Code that starts activity for result from the 3rd party SDK */
}
```

}

Handle onActivityResult: In your ViewModel, override the onActivityResult method and update the ViewModel's state with the received result.

```
class MyViewModel : ViewModel() {
// ...

fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
    if (requestCode == THIRD_PARTY_REQUEST_CODE) {
        // Handle the result from the 3rd party SDK and update your state accordingly
    }
}
```

}

Observe ViewModel in Composable: In your Composable, observe the ViewModel and use the result to update your UI.

```
    @Composable
    fun MyComposable(viewModel: MyViewModel) {
    // Observe the ViewModel using stateFlow or other state management mechanisms
    val result = viewModel.myResultStateFlow.collectAsState()

    Column {
        // Display UI based on the result
        if (result.value != null) {
            // Display the result data in your UI
        }

        Button(onClick = { viewModel.startThirdPartyActivity() }) {
            Text("Start 3rd Party Activity")
        }
    }
}
```

Connect ViewModel in Activity: Finally, in your Activity, initialize and provide the ViewModel to your Composable.

```
class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {
private val viewModel: MyViewModel by viewModels()

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContent {
        MyComposable(viewModel)
    }
}

override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)
    viewModel.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)
}
```

}

This way, when the 3rd party SDK's activity returns a result, the onActivityResult in the ViewModel will be triggered, and the ViewModel's state will be updated. This change in state will then trigger a recomposition of your Composable, allowing you to update the UI based on the result.